# Android Holo Dialog has 2 backgrounds layered on top of one another

Tags: android

[image]

The dialog looks like this. There is a layer behind the dialog itself about 10-20 pixels or so on each side. The theme I am using is Theme.Holo.Dialog

I tried creating a custom dialog with a transparent background, but that did not work:

```
<style name="CustomHoloDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
     <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: How are you building the dialog? And how are you styling it?(With a `ContextThemeWrapper`
?)

Comment: I'm building the dialog with an AlertDialog.Builder object. (`builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.CustomHoloDialog);`).

I don't believe I'm using a ContextThemeWrapper, I'm looking into that right now.

Comment: @Ahmad you should put that in the form of an answer, so I can +1 it. Changing the theme back to android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog in a ContextThemeWrapper works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to style a Dialog then you have to use a `ContextThemeWrapper`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog));
```