# Android Dialog with Holo theme with libGDX looks weird

Tags: android, dialog, libgdx

I want to show a "confirm exit" Holo Dialog in my libGDX project. This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder bld;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10) {
        //With default theme looks perfect:
        bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidLauncher.this);
    } else {
        //With Holo theme appears the double Dialog:
        bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidLauncher.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_MinWidth);
    }

    bld.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    bld.setTitle("Exit");
    bld.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
    bld.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { dialog.dismiss(); }
    });
    bld.setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { finish(); }
    });
    bld.setCancelable(false);
    bld.create().show();
}
```

The Dialog works, but with the Holo theme appears with an ugly background.

This are the results, with a non-Holo theme:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/XlCFTd4.jpg]

And the ugly result with Holo theme:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/NEfMsMy.png]

How can I show a Holo Dialog without the ugly "double Dialog"? Thanks!

Comment: possible similar issue : https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/199

Comment: and this may contain a solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125220/android-holo-dialog-has-2-backgrounds-layered-on-top-of-one-another

Comment: Thanks moujib! ContextThemeWrapper solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

instead of

`bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidLauncher.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_MinWidth);`

use

`bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(AndroidLauncher.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_MinWidth));`

Comment: I already solved the problem thanks to moujib comment, but thanks anyway!